# SQL - Select top after ordering results

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I need to order an amount of points received in a period for a category then take the top 2 as you can only count your two highest point totals in a period. Currently my query looks like this but it is not working. It currently is just ordering the results after selecting 2.

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM player as p 
INNER JOIN  player_event as pe ON p.PID=pe.PID 
INNER JOIN event as e ON pe.EID=e.EID
WHERE e.ESeasonID=171801 AND e.ECat='Cup/Challenge'
ORDER BY pe.PEPts DESC
```

Comment: test this :  `Select top 2 * from (your query without top 2)`

Comment: Your query should be fine.  It is ordering before doing the `TOP`.

Comment: I tried adding select top 2 and it throws the error "Failed to execute query. Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with limit 2

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM player as p 
    INNER JOIN  player_event as pe ON p.PID=pe.PID 
    INNER JOIN event as e ON pe.EID=e.EID
    WHERE e.ESeasonID=171801 AND e.ECat='Cup/Challenge'
    ORDER BY pe.PEPts DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: It won't accept the LIMIT or the ;. I am using Azure's SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of the result set usually takes place near the very end of the query processing.  Try using a window function to get what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM player as p 
INNER JOIN player_event as pe ON p.PID=pe.PID 
INNER JOIN event as e ON pe.EID=e.EID
WHERE e.ESeasonID=171801 AND e.ECat='Cup/Challenge'
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pe.PEPts DESC) <=2
```

This query above should work on Teradata.  If you are on Postgres or another system that doesn't support QUALIFY, you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.*, pe.*, e.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pe.PEPts DESC) AS RowNum
  FROM player as p 
  INNER JOIN player_event as pe ON p.PID=pe.PID 
  INNER JOIN event as e ON pe.EID=e.EID
  WHERE e.ESeasonID=171801 AND e.ECat='Cup/Challenge'
) src
WHERE RowNum <=2
```

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pe.PEPts) assigns each row a "row number" based on the ordering specified in the (ORDER BY ...).  QUALIFY in Teradata is equivalent to a WHERE clause, but only for window functions.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what I am on (Azure's SQL database default I guess) but it would not take the QUALIFY and then the second option threw an error "Failed to execute query. Error: The column 'PID' was specified multiple times for 'src'." That to me means it wanted to work but maybe I messed up the syntax somewhere?

Comment: Try modifying the `SELECT p.*, pe.*, e.*` line to only select the fields you want.  Maybe it's implicitly returning a PID column for each of those tables.

Comment: I got it working. I had a data entry error. The original query and your second query both worked great. Thank you.

Comment: You got it dude :)

Answer (score 0):

This query would give you the top 2 players based on the points for the season and category supplied

```
SELECT v1.PID, v1.EID, v1.PEPts
FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.PID, e.EID, pe.PEPts
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.ESeasonID, e.ECat ORDER BY pe.PEPts DESC) AS r_num
  FROM player as p 
  INNER JOIN player_event as pe ON p.PID=pe.PID 
  INNER JOIN event as e ON pe.EID=e.EID
  WHERE e.ESeasonID=171801 AND e.ECat='Cup/Challenge'
) v1
WHERE r_num <= 2;
```